# Parsing Json with for in loop in python

Tags: python, json

I have the following sample code which parses JSON file from API

```
for query in r["queries"]:
    print(query["attributes"]["planning_wait_time"])
```

This gives me result:

```
5986
5987
42
0
63
5978
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./query_warning.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(query["attributes"]["planning_wait_time"])
KeyError: 'planning_wait_time'
```

The numbers that you see are the correct numbers for planning_wait_time, I can only assume that the reason I'm getting KeyError is because not all the information in my JSON text includes planning_wait_time.
Is there a way to bypass the error? I only need results if JSON has planning_wait_time
Thanks

Comment: query["attributes"].get("planning_wait_time") can work. With this get method it return None if there is no such key, so you can add a if condition here

Comment: @ozcanyarimdunya exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the key

```
for q in r["queries"]:
    attrs = q["attributes"]
    if "planning_wait_time" in attrs:
        print(attrs["planning_wait_time"])
```

Or if you are okay seeing `None` or want something else, use `.get()`

```
for q in r["queries"]:
    print(q["attributes"].get("planning_wait_time"))  # You can add a parameter here for a default value
```